# Graph Isomorphism Problem

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-isomorphism

I am doing some literature review on Graph isomorphism problem. Most of papers which I am reading are written by E.M Luks and Laszlo Babai. 
These papers uses the high level knowledge of group theory and complexity theory.
As I am new to this field many of the things are not clear to me.

Can some one suggest me a way to learn ideas and techniques which are presented in these papers so that I can come up with some other ideas.

Thank you so much

Comment: See also related question http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/12369/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I highly recommend [Paolo Codenotti's thesis](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/students/codenotti.pdf) for the group-theoretic aspects, and the book *The Graph Isomorphism Problem: Its Structural Complexity* by Johannes Köbler, Uwe Schöning, and Jacobo Torán for the complexity aspects.

Answer (score -4):

http://oeis.org/A186202 is the best you can do for automorphism by brute force permutation checking.